# script for Checking the number of LDAP entries on LDAP.CONF on client machines and updating the missing ones

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to use sed command in a script to search for the line which starts with HOST and then check for a matching pattern of host names and add the missing ones on the LDAP configuration file.

SAMPLE ENTRY IN LDAP.CONF

```
HOST nzlsfn55.zeus.ghsewn.com nzlsfn60.zeus.ghsewn.com  nznsfn60.zeus.ghsewn.com
```

Now how do i search for the pattern and add the missing entries using sed , any help would be much appreciated .

Comment: Can you show a _before_ & _after_ example ? I think the '*' characters are typos, no ?

Comment: Hey @sputnick thanks for the reply, example would be like say if the HOST entry is missing one or two host names from the above listed host names.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of hosts and want to add those missing :

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg; do
    grep &>/dev/null "^HOST \+.*\<$arg\>" ||
        sed -i "s/$/ $arg/" /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
done
```

Use the script like this :

```
./script host1 host2 host3
```

Backup your `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` before testing. (not tested there)

**EDIT**

To fit your new requirements, see the following code :

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts="host1 host2 host3"

for arg in $hosts; do
    grep &>/dev/null "^HOST \+.*\<$arg\>" ||
        sed -i "s/$/ $arg/" /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
done
```

Comment: hey that's awesome, I have a predefined list of hosts which i think embed in to the script instead of passing it as arguments - what say ?

Comment: hey why is this script taking a long time to run ? any idea - it just hungup on the command line, did u test this ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `GNU awk` for this. Assuming you have a list of hosts (line separated) in a file called `hosts.txt`, you could run the following:

```
awk -f script.awk hosts.txt /etc/ldap/ldap.conf > new_ldap.conf
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FNR==NR {
    hosts[$0]++
    next
}

/^HOST/ {
    for (j=2; j<=NF; j++) {
        array[$j]++
    }
    for (i in hosts) {
        if (!(i in array)) {
            $0 = $0 OFS i
        }
    }
    delete array
}1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this code below to achieve my task, i am sure there must me much easier way or improvement needed to my piece of code - thanks guys for your input

if [ -e /etc/openldap/ldap.conf ];
    then

```
        entries=`grep -i host /etc/openldap/ldap.conf`

        count=`grep -i host /etc/openldap/ldap.conf | wc -w`


else

        echo " no ldap.conf file available "
        exit

fi

#if condition checking for no host entry

if [ $count -eq 0 ];
then


        echo " no host entry available in config file "
        exit

fi


#if condition checking for less than 3 ldap entries

if [ $count -eq 4 ];
then

        echo " `hostname` has the following ldap entries : $entries "
else

        #less then than 3 entries will get updated here
        if [ $count -lt 4 ];
        then

        sed -i.bak 's/^host.*\|^HOST.*/host nzlsfn55.zeus.ghsewn.com nzlsfn60.zeus.ghsewn.com  nznsfn60.zeus.ghsewn.com/' /etc/openldap/ldap.conf

        echo " Sucessfully added LDAP hosts"

        fi
```